# IP tables - changes not persisting

Tags: firewall, iptables, port

I've tried to open port 8605 on my server (used for socket connections) using:

```
iptables -I INPUT 2 -s 0/0 -p tcp --dport 8605 -j ACCEPT
```

However the change is not persisting, the port closes itself once a day (I assume something is being regularly reloaded).

How can I make my change persist?

**EDIT**

Despite saving it, the change does not persist, each day it needs to be corrected.

Crontab does not seem to have any obvious changes, and the server is not restarting. Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I found out that iptables was running under [apf - advanced policy firewall](http://www.rfxn.com/projects/advanced-policy-firewall/) so I needed to updated the rules in there.

Comment: Kind thanks to all the answers, I have performed a save and will update if this doesn't resolve the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your system is fedora-derived add the rule in **`/etc/sysconfig/iptables`**.

If you have already added your rule you should simply do a **`service iptables save`**.

You can always do
- `service iptables save`
- **edit** `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` as you need
- `service iptables restart`

Answer (score 1):

You should mention if you are using RedHat or a Debian based system.  With redhat / Centos, the `service iptables save` command should work.

Answer (score 1):

When you call `iptables`, you're changing the rules that are running, but that information isn't stored anywhere to be re-applied. To do that, you want to execute `iptables` statements on load. If you're not rebooting your server every day, I don't know what's resetting `iptables`, but there are lots of packages to help you by being useful front-ends. Ubuntu has `ufw`, RH/Fedora-based distros have `system-config-securitylevel`, and there are dozens of others. These typically apply the change *and* persist it to a script for when things are next reloaded.